# Is there a maximum number of buttons that can be added in an activity or layout?

Tags: android, button

I am developing an android app which needs 26 buttons in an activity layout. I am able to add 16 buttons without any errors or problems. When I try to add the rest of the buttons the layout gets unresolved id cannot be resolved.

```
Error:layout cannot be resolved or is not a field.
```

Any suggestions to proceed?

Links to the code:

Main java file where error is occuring:
http://code.google.com/p/my-abcd/source/browse/LearnABCDActivity.java

XML file where all 26 buttons are placed using a grid layout
http://code.google.com/p/my-abcd/source/browse/svn/main.xml

My observation: 
The id's identified using "findViewByid" are getting unresolved or considered not a id anymore after I try to add more buttons (i.e., >16 buttons). Till alphabet P the code is fine. Only when I try to add alphabet Q (Button Q) and beyond the things gets unnoticed resulting in an error. I think the R.java file is getting corrupted after adding the 17th button.
Hope this info helps .

Comment: Can you post the code you use to add the buttons?

Comment: Do you add the buttons by code or you put them in the xml layout? Can you post the error?

Comment: Post your code and show your logcat

Comment: Can you post which layout you using?

Answer (score 0):

You must be getting `OutofMemoryException`. This usually happens when device is not capable of holding more controls in Current Heap Memory ( RAM ).

Comment: @Lucifer:  
code.google.com/p/my-abcd/source/browse/svn/main.xml 
 
code.google.com/p/my-abcd/source/browse/LearnABCDActivity.java

Comment: Lucifer: I have pasted two links one to the main java file where i am getting the error when I try to add the rest of the buttons.i.e., from R to Z alphabets

Comment: and the other link is to the main layout where all the buttons are placed in a grid layout without any error.

Comment: do one thing, first try to run with two rows of Button after then with four rows .... like so you will be able to catch the error fast.

Comment: @Lucifer: The app has a main activity with 26 image buttons and upon clicking on each one will lead to the particular alphabet. The problem I am facing is not being able to add >17 image buttons i.e., from alphabet R onwards I cannot add image buttons and make them available to click(using onClicklistener) inorder to go to the alphabets activities accordingly.The app works perfectly fine when we move from one activity to another (from A to Z alphabets).

Comment: can you send me your project ?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B_w5Xyo59QFbMTU4Y2QzODYtMTcyYS00MmNiLThiM2MtODRkNGZmMGUzMTli

Answer (score 0):

See my app screen shot with more buttons, I am not getting any error.

[image]

The error you posted is related to your code only. Post the code you are using, otherwise it is difficult to find the problem.

Comment: @Archana which API level you are using ? The code you linked here requires API level 14.

Comment: I am using API level 15 (4.0.3 platform)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the button name I was using which was causing the layout to be unrecognised.

I was using the letter "R" which was causing the problem in my code.